# Existence of solution of $y'=\frac { y \ln(y) }{\sin(x) }$ in given intervals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given is the O.D.E 
$y'=\dfrac { y\, \ln(y) }{ \sin(x) } $ with the I.V.P $y({ x }_{ 0 })={ y }_{ 0 }$

the general solution to this Equation is $y(x)={ e }^{ { e }^{ { c }_{ 1 } }\tan(\frac { x }{ 2 } ) }$

by adapting our arbitrary constant this become equivalent to $ y(x)={ e }^{ { c }_{ 1 }\tan(\frac { x }{ 2 } ) }$

The question is now if there exists a solution to the I.V.P in these intervals
$(0,\pi )$, $(\pi ,2\pi )$ with ${ x }_{ 0 }\in (0,\pi )$, ${ x }_{ 0 } \in (\pi ,2\pi )$

First of all I don't fully get the Statement of the I.V.P, does this mean we are looking at arbitrary start values? and moreover since our solution is defined in those intervals wouldn't there be always a solution to an arbitrary I.V.P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODE is not defined at $x=k\pi$, $k\in\Bbb Z$, as the right side has poles there. The task seems to ask if these are the only restrictions on the maximal interval of a solution, as sometimes singularities appear "dynamically" like in $y'=y^2$. The only other restriction from the ODE itself is $y>0$.

You should now observe that in the solution process there appear no additional divisions by terms that can be potentially zero, and that the solution formula has only the already accounted for singularities, and that they stay singularities of the solutions.